# Fill up the remaining width inside inline-block parent div

Tags: css

There is a `#wrapper` div set to `inline-block` which I cannot change or add anything for some reason.

I need a table display inside the `#wrapper` div:

```css
#page {
  display: block;
  background-color: #dd3333;
}

#wrapper {
  /* Cannot change this: */
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #33dd33;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
          Table cell 1
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          Table cell 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
          Table cell A
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          Table cell B
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, `.table` does not fill up the whole width because of the `#wrapper`. I want "Table cell 1" and "Table cell 2" to fill up the **whole screen with equal columns**. Is there a pure css solution to this?

(This could have been solved easily by removing the `#wrapper` div, some js to change its `display` property, or move `.table` out of `#wrapper`.)

Comment: are you not able to write extra css...?

Comment: I can, but cannot edit the `#wrapper` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `width:100%` to the `#wrapper` div

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#page {
  display: block;
  background-color: #dd3333;
}

#wrapper {
  /* Cannot change this: */
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #33dd33;
  width:100%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell">
        Table cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        Table cell 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Updated:*** If you don't want to change the `#wrapper` div, you can use css child selector `>` like

```
#page>div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
#page {
  display: block;
  background-color: #dd3333;
}

#page>div {
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  /* Cannot change this: */
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #33dd33;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell">
        Table cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        Table cell 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I actually cannot change/add anything inside `#wrapper`. (Edited the question to be more clear.)

Comment: @NeigylR.Noval you can write an another extra css rule for `#wrapper`...is this possible...check second solution...

Comment: I can if that's the only way. Edit: `#page>div` is a nice work-around. I will mark this answer as accepted if I can't find a cleaner way.